# can't log requests when socket.io enabled

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to debug a socket.io problem. In order to figure out what's happening, I'd like to log all requests, so I have installed morgan.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
var path = require('path');    
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);  // this line prevents morgan from logging
```

Logging works fine until I require socket.io- that last line there apparently prevents morgan from seeing all the requests.

Why is socket.io preventing the rest of the stack from seeing requests?

**Edit**:

Something of an explanation [here](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/): apparently socket.io is too verbose, and debugging is turned off by default. If I run with `DEBUG=*` set in my environment, I get lots more information.

This does seem rather unfriendly to the rest of the stack though.

Comment: Try this var io = require('socket.io').listen(app,{log :false}); to disabled log by socket.io.

Comment: The explanation link in your answer is broken, and using the Wayback Machine with the link also does not work. Can you update the link to have a working explanation page again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `DEBUG=*` can be way too verbose but the debug module also lets you specify comma separated list of wildcardable patterns. Some examples:

```
DEBUG=socket.io*
DEBUG=socket.io*,engine:*
DEBUG=socket.io:socket,engine:socket
```